# Проблема с Binding у UserControl`а

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, usercontrol

MainWindow.xaml

```
<local:VideoPlayerControl SourceVideo="{Binding Test}"/>
<Button Command="{Binding command}" Width="100" Height="100"></Button>
```

MainViewModel.cs (: INotifyPropertyChanged)

```
private Uri _Test = new Uri(@"D:\Videos\1.mp4", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    public Uri Test
    {
        get { return _Test; }
        set { _Test = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    public ICommand command { get; }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        command = new RelayCommand(o => { Test = new Uri(@"D:\Videos\3.mp4", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute); });
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "") => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
```

VideoPlayerControl.xaml

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:VideoPlayerVM/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
    <MediaElement Source="{Binding ElementName=UserControlmain, Path=SourceVideo}" LoadedBehavior="Pause" UnloadedBehavior="Manual"/>
```

VideoPlayerControl.xaml.cs

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceVideoProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SourceVideo", typeof(Uri), typeof(VideoPlayerControl), new PropertyMetadata(new Uri(@"D:\Videos\1.mp4", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), OnSourceVideoChanged));
    public Uri SourceVideo
    {
        get { return (Uri)GetValue(SourceVideoProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SourceVideoProperty, value); MessageBox.Show(SourceVideo.ToString()); }
    }
    private static void OnSourceVideoChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SourceVideoProperty, e.NewValue);
    }
```

А VideoPlayerVM пустой

Проблема в том что при клике на кнопку по задумке Test меняется но путь к новому видео
В MainWindow.xaml VideoPlayerControl устанавливается новый путь дальше через Binding к MediaElement устанавливается новый путь.

Вместо задуманного ничего не происходит и в выводе выводиться ошибка
`System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Test' property not found on 'object' ''VideoPlayerVM' (HashCode=33624151)'. BindingExpression:Path=Test; DataItem='VideoPlayerVM' (HashCode=33624151); target element is 'VideoPlayerControl' (Name='UserControlmain'); target property is 'SourceVideo' (type 'Uri')`

Как исправить эту проблему? Или подскажите пожалуйста способ легче и грамотней.

Comment: А как вы устанавливаете DataContext для MainWindow?

Comment: Также как для VideoPlayerControl.

Comment: Тоже `<local:VideoPlayerVM/>`?

Comment: <local:MainViewModel/>

Comment: А почему-то ищет свойство `Test` в экземпляре `VideoPlayerVM`. Что-то вы напутали, вообще для начала рекомендую устанавливать `DataContext` извне, а не внутри View, т.к. это не ее область ответственности.

Comment: Да насчет того что ищет в VideoPlayerVM я удивился но если я  удаляю класс VideoPlayerVM тогда просто ничего не происходит без ошибок даже

Comment: Не знаю почему но свойство Test пытается взяться из VideoControlVM (наверно из DataContext VIdeoPlayerControl) тоесть из DataContext элемента а не окна!

Comment: Попробуйте так исправить привязку: `SourceVideo="{Binding DataContext.Test, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"`

Comment: Не к сожалению не работает. Есть еще идея как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Ну как я написал выше, переделать так, чтобы вьюха не создавала сама себе DataContext это неправильно и я подозреваю, что проблема именно где-то здесь

Comment: Так я исправил и добавил и в VideoPlayerControl.xaml.cs в контруктор this.DataContext = new VideoPlayerVM(); и в MainWindow.xaml.cs также только MainViewModel

Comment: Почему то OnPropertyChanged() не обновляет привязку к SourceVideo хотя Test меняется

Comment: Могу скинуть ссылку на Google диск с проектом так будет легче помочь

Comment: Ну так все равно вьюха сама себе создаёт VM получается.

Comment: А как это? Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: А кто у вас создаёт MainWindow? Вот он пусть и устанавливает DataContext. Подозреваю, что это происходит в App.xaml, значит надо убрать автоматическое создание и написать в App.xaml.cs в OnStartup создание окна и vm для него

Comment: Аналогично DataContext для контроля, пусть его устанавливает родительское окно

Comment: 1) а разве это грамотно в паттерне mvvm? 2) а в чем ошибка? Ведь ничего не пишет просто меняется Test а в SourceVideo не обновляется